# Why are my text elements not centered properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my text elements centered like they would be in MS word.
I am currently using: `text-align: center;` to center the text but the result looks like it is flushed left in the center of the page rather than centered the way I want.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```css
#onp {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: gothambold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 20px
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: gothambold;
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: gothambold;
  src: url(gothambold.ttf)
}

@font-face {
  font-family: gothamlight;
  src: url(gothamlight.ttf)
}

#linklist {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

#linklist p {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: gothambold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>x - home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#ffeeee;">
  <h1>XXX XXXXXX</h1>
  <p id="onp"> online portfolio</p>
  <div id="linklist">
    <p>photography</p>
    <p>design</p>
    <p>case study</p>
    <p>contact</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to fix this issue before moving on and I've been trying for a while with no luck.

Cheers

EDIT: After running the snippet on this website, the text looks fine. On my machine with the font that I'm using, the text definitely looks flushed. What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `padding-right: 40px;` I changed to `20px` but also added `padding-left: 20px;` and a `lime border` so you can see whats going on.. hope that helps:

```css
#onp {
 text-align:center;
 font-family: gothambold;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 20px
}

h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 font-family: gothambold;
 text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: gothambold;
 src: url(gothambold.ttf)
}

@font-face {
 font-family: gothamlight;
 src: url(gothamlight.ttf)
}

#linklist {
 text-align: center;
 width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin: auto;
 
}

#linklist p {
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
 font-family: gothambold;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>x - home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ffeeee;">  
        <h1>XXX XXXXXX</h1>
        <p id="onp"> online portfolio</p>
    <div id="linklist">
        <p>photography</p>
        <p>design</p>
        <p>case study</p>
        <p>contact</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked on my horizontal list but the "online portfolio" is still flushed for me

Comment: @T.Little if you can not reproduce the problem here it's hard to say what's causing it. But I'll activate my magician lamp and try :) ok, seriously, you have included something else css or js which changes the styles. use the website inspector and move on the elements from top to bottom and then you'll find it.

Comment: I had ended up removing the "online portfolio" and putting it in my menu bar instead. Your tips on padding has helped have helped me resolve any future problems of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-right` from `#linklist p` and add `padding-left` in `#linklist p + p`, it's added padding `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<p>`

```css
#onp {
  text-align:center;
  font-family: gothambold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 20px
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: gothambold;
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: gothambold;
  src: url(gothambold.ttf)
}

@font-face {
  font-family: gothamlight;
  src: url(gothamlight.ttf)
}

#linklist {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

#linklist p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: gothambold;
}
#linklist p + p {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>x - home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ffeeee;">  
  <h1>XXX XXXXXX</h1>
  <p id="onp"> online portfolio</p>
  <div id="linklist">
    <p>photography</p>
    <p>design</p>
    <p>case study</p>
    <p>contact</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has worked but like I told caramba, "Thank you, this has worked on my horizontal list but the 'online portfolio' is still flushed for me"